# Is there any difference between these two one-to-many relationships?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
class City(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    cityname = db.Column(db.String(50))
    country_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('country.id'))
    country = db.relationship('Country',
                              backref=db.backref('cities', lazy='dynamic'))

class Country(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    countryname = db.Column(db.String(50))
```

Is there any difference between these two one-to-many relationships?

```
class City(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    cityname = db.Column(db.String(50))
    country_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('country.id'))


class Country(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    countryname = db.Column(db.String(50))
    cities = db.relationship('City', backref='country', lazy='dynamic')
```

Are these two identical methods for capturing that a Country has many cities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the two methods achieve the same effect of one-to-many relationship (the table construct is identical), the difference being *where the relationship is declared*.

My personal preference is to declare the relationship on **both** models, as it is more explicit and helps with the IDE (auto-complete). You can do this using [back_populates](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.back_populates) in place of `backref`.

> Takes a string name and has the same meaning as backref, except the
>   complementing property is not created automatically, and instead must
>   be configured explicitly on the other mapper. The complementing
>   property should also indicate back_populates to this relationship to
>   ensure proper functioning.

```py
class City(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    country_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('country.id'))
    country = db.relationship('Country', back_populates='cities')

class Country(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    cities = db.relationship('City', back_populates='country')
```