# SQLalchemy and ambiguous ForeignKeys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

(*Update*: a full working code sample is [here](http://pythonfiddle.com/distinguished-one-among-many-to-one).)

This [Many-To-One](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45767779/8099646) relationship

```
class City(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True)
    country_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('country.id'))
    country = db.relationship('Country', back_populates='cities')

class Country(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True)
    cities = db.relationship('City', back_populates='country')
```

can be [augmented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45767985/8099646) by distinguishing one among the many, say as the capital.

Of these two solutions, adding a separate table is feasible

```
class Capital(db.Model):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/q/45767923/8099646
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    country = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('country.id'))
    capital = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('city.id'))
```

but a better solution is to avoid the extra table and simply insert a field:

```
class Country(db.Model):
    ...
    capital = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('city.id'))
```

Why does SQLalchemy complain about `AmbiguousForeignKeysError` when that line is added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is now SQLAlchemy doesn't know what join condition the `country`/`cities` relationship refers to because there are two possibilities (namely `country_id` and `capital`).

The way to fix this is to explicitly specify `foreign_keys`:

```
class City(db.Model):
    ...
    country = db.relationship('Country', foreign_keys=country_id, back_populates='cities')

class Country(db.Model):
    ...
    cities = db.relationship('City', foreign_keys=City.country_id, back_populates='country')
```

Note that this kind of circular pattern will also result in `CircularDependencyError` when creating the tables (because each cannot be created without the other) and when inserting with two interdependent relationships (because each row cannot be inserted without the other row's id). So the full solution is to set `use_alter` on one of the `ForeignKey`s (to issue an `ALTER` when creating tables in order to break the cycle) and `post_update` on one of the `relationship`s (to issue an `UPDATE` when inserting in order to break the cycle):

```
class City(db.Model):
    ...
    country_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('country.id'))
    country = db.relationship('Country', foreign_keys=country_id, back_populates='cities')

class Country(db.Model):
    ...
    capital_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('city.id', use_alter=True))
    capital = db.relationship(City, foreign_keys=capital_id, post_update=True)
    cities = db.relationship(City, foreign_keys=City.country_id, back_populates='country')
```

Comment: I feel you pointed to a blind spot in my knowledge. Can you mention a few keywords so I can pursue a reference? To read more would I look in the textbook database literature (on relational databases), the SQL mechanics (aside from sqlalchemy), or sqlalchemy in particular?

Comment: @Sebastian It's hard to answer that question since I don't know what you don't know, but I'll mention a few things that you might want to get a deeper understanding of: 1. how to model relationships using foreign keys using only SQL; 2. `CREATE TABLE` with two tables that refer to each other via foreign keys (and why it's not possible without `ALTER`); 3. `INSERT` two rows with autoincrement primary keys that refer to each other using foreign keys (and why it's not possible without `UPDATE`); 4. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.exc.CircularDependencyError